Zada, Hedron Grinder and Leyline of Resonance
I have Zada, Hedron Grinder on the battlefield and Leyline of Resonance. When I now cast a spell that targets only Zada, Hedron Grinder, Leyline of Resonance creates a copy of that spell and I can target a creature. If I now target the copy, does this copy also copies itself to each other creature on my battlefield? Or is it like just one copy more than other creatures on my battlefield.

"If I now target the copy" Target it with what? Do you mean "target Zada with the copy"?

Zada, Hedron Grinder and Leyline of Resonance have no interaction. Both Zada and the Leyline create copies of the original spell, but the copies cannot be copied by them because they are not cast.
Both Zada and the Leyline trigger on you casting a spell. However, when you copy a spell, the copies are not cast, and neither Zada nor Leyline will trigger:

707.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. [..]

So in the end Zada will copy the spell once for each other creature, targeting them, and Leyline will copy the spell once with any new target.

Note that there are a number of cards (such as Wildfire Devils) that do let you cast copies of spells, but those cards all explicitly say so. It has to do with where the card being copied is - if you copy a spell on the stack the copy appears on the stack without being cast, but if you copy a card in exile the copy must be cast to move from exile to the stack

@ArcanistLupus - Indeed. For additional context: in those cases, you're creating a copy of a card and then casting it, at which point it becomes a spell. The rules are technically correct that "a copy of a spell isn't cast," because casting is the process by which a "card" (in hand, exile, the graveyard, or the command zone) becomes a "spell" (on the stack). Players often use "spell" and "nonland card that isn't currently on the battlefield as a permanent" interchangeably informally, but the rules distinguish the two.
